# Android - How to work with nested ListViews

Tags: android, xml, api, listview, nested

this is my first question on this site and I am also new to Android. I am creating an application using an online API. I am working with this API in XML and parsing the responses into ListViews. I have reached a point where I would like to select an item from a ListView in one activity and send that information to the next activity along with another ListView containing more information for the selected item. As an example, one activity has a list of bands. Clicking on the band name will bring up the band name and a list of tour dates on the next activity. According to my API, the band's ID number is needed to access the bands tour information I am trying to pass the ID number as a search parameter but cannot get this to work. I did manage to find a decent tutorial on androidhive.info but cannot seem to be able to apply these techniques. The doInBackground() method is where my app is hanging up.

```
        ListView lv = getListView();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String displayName = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDisplayName)).getText().toString();
                String onTourUntil = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvOnTourUntil)).getText().toString();
                String identification = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvId)).getText().toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleArtistActivity.class);
                in.putExtra(KEY_DISPLAY_NAME, displayName);
                in.putExtra(KEY_ID, identification);
                in.putExtra(KEY_ON_TOUR_UNTIL, onTourUntil);

                new AsyncDownload().execute(identification);

                startActivity(in);
            }
        });
```

}

```
private class AsyncDownload extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ArtistsSearchActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");

        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        Log.v(TAG, "query is" +  params[0]);
        String result = new ArtistCalendarHelper().getXml(params[0]);
        return result;
    }
```

My AsyncDownload class is called in my onClickListener. The class calls a helper that contains the URL and API key.

```
public class ArtistCalendarHelper {
    private static final String TAG = "ArtistCalendarHelper";
    private static final String SONGKICK_URL = "http://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/artists/";
    private static final String API_KEY = "yIekMi1hQzcFheKc";

public String getXml(String identification) {

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    String getParameters = "";
    try {
        getParameters = URLEncoder.encode(identification, "UTF-8") 
                + "/calendar.xml?apikey=" + URLEncoder.encode(API_KEY, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    String url = SONGKICK_URL + getParameters;
    // Prepare a request object
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

    // Execute the request
    HttpResponse response;
```

These methods worked for obtaining the bands name in an initial search. How could this be changed to perform a search for tour information with an argument retrieved from a ListView?
Is this different from getting a search query from an EditText field? I didn't think there would be much of a difference. I have tried to include the affected code. I am not sure how much code I should provide.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:
 step 1.  Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleArtistActivity.class);
                in.putExtra(KEY_DISPLAY_NAME, displayName);
                in.putExtra(KEY_ID, identification);
                in.putExtra(KEY_ON_TOUR_UNTIL, onTourUntil);

```
           // new AsyncDownload().execute(identification); dont start the net request here

            startActivity(in);
```

step 2.
       put on request url method in second Activity's on create() method
       public class SingleArtistActivity{

```
       onCrete(){
        ...
      new AsyncDownload().execute(identification);
```

}
    in SingleArtistActivity, instance a empty Adapter,  call method : listView.setAdapter(adapter), then the view will show but the listview is empty ,no data will display, but the url request is working in background.
}

step 3:
     when the AsyncTask return the data , put the data into a List data;
   then call the   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
   the listview will reload the apapter again , the data will be display in the listview

Comment: When would "identification" be assigned? That is why I kept this statement in the first activity.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a mistake here:

```
            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleArtistActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(KEY_DISPLAY_NAME, displayName);
            in.putExtra(KEY_ID, identification);
            in.putExtra(KEY_ON_TOUR_UNTIL, onTourUntil);

            new AsyncDownload().execute(identification);

            startActivity(in);
```

I guess you want to load the data with AsyncDownload then show them in SingleArtistActivity.class. 
So you should put these code in SingleArtistActivity.java.

You should call new AsyncDownload().execute(identification);in onCreate() or onResume() of SingleArtistActivity.java ;
and setAdapter in onPostExecute of your AsyncDownload class.
like these:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute() {
    if(pDialog != null && pDialog.showing()) {
         pDialog.dismiss();
    } 
    YourAdapter adapter = new Adapter(yourdata);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```